# Why didn't the 4th Doctor come back for Sarah Jane?

Tags: doctor-who

School Reunion was an accident.  The Doctor said he'd come back and he had many chances, so why didn't he do it?

Comment: There was a [spin-off pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-9_and_Company) and she was in [The Five Doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Five_Doctors). She must have received K-9 from someone...

Comment: Did you actually watch the episode? He explained it in the one you're asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's allow the Doctor to explain it himself. From the transcript of *School Reunion*:

> SARAH: Did I do something wrong, because you never came back for me. You just dumped me.
>   DOCTOR: I told you. I was called back home and in those days humans weren't allowed.
>   SARAH: I waited for you. I missed you.
>   DOCTOR: Oh, you didn't need me. You were getting on with your life.
>   [...]
>   SARAH: You could have come back.
>   DOCTOR: I couldn't.
>   SARAH: Why not?
>   (The Doctor keeps working on K9.)

And later on:

> DOCTOR: I don't age. I regenerate. But humans decay. You wither and you die. Imagine watching that happen to someone who you ...
>   ROSE: What, Doctor?
>   DOCTOR: You can spend the rest of your life with me, but I can't spend the rest of mine with you. I have to live on. Alone. That's the curse of the Time Lords.

So it seems to be a mixture of a few reasons, although the first two may be untrue while the fourth is what he doesn't want to admit:

- he was called back to Gallifrey and couldn't take her with him
- he wanted to let her get on with her life
- he couldn't keep her with him forever and saw it as a good opportunity to split up
- **he simply forgot about her**.

Comment: I think there’s a bit of dialogue later in the episode suggesting that actually it’s just quite painful for the Doctor to watch his companions grow old and die. (I should, of course, look this up.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "DOCTOR: I don't age. I regenerate. But humans decay. You wither and you die. Imagine watching that happen to someone who you ...
ROSE: What, Doctor? 
DOCTOR: You can spend the rest of your life with me, but I can't spend the rest of mine with you. I have to live on. Alone. That's the curse of the Time Lords."

Comment: That’s the one.

Comment: Thanks.  He probably did just forget about her, he seems to do that a lot.  It's a bit disapointing really though, I kinda expected better, and how can you forget someone who has saved the world with you?

Comment: It's kinda weird to get 5 upvotes on a comment and none on the answer... @ThatDoctorFan I added another quote and reason based on what PaulD.Waite mentioned. Is this enough to get the tick for correct answer? :-)

Comment: Well, you still have “he simply forgot about her” in bold, and I don’t think you’ve provided any supporting evidence for that idea.

Comment: @rand al'thor I am so sorry and I would like to as it's a fantastic answer but I'm new to this and don't know how.  Please can you tell me, as I think it is the right answer, and there is no less disappointing one.  Disappointing because of the Doctor, not you.  You were great.

Comment: @ThatDoctorFan On the left of the answer, below the score and the upvote/downvote buttons, there's another grey symbol which is meant to be a checkmark; clicking on that marks this answer as 'accepted'. This is not permanent, and you can always change it if someone else posts a better answer.

Comment: I think those first 3 suggestions are just rationalising, and the 4th is much closer to the mark... although of course in at least one late story Sarah Jane does suggest she's considering leaving to get on with her life, and yet I don't think the Doctor would do it intentionally because of that.  Although of course there is another possibility...

Answer (score 1):

### The TARDIS intervened

Although we don't often think of the TARDIS as a sentient character, she is (and has been known to be since the very earliest stories, too).  And is later stated explicitly, she sometimes takes the Doctor to places that aren't his *intended* destination simply because the place he ends up is, in some sense, better for him.

One of these occasions interrupted the Doctor at the time when he should have been going back to collect Sarah Jane.  At the end of *The Hand of Fear* (bad name, and unfortunately not the greatest episode either), Sarah Jane is annoyed with the Doctor and looking forward to some time away from him:

> DOCTOR: Forget the zeus plug. I'll have the sonic screwdriver.
>
> SARAH:
> Oh, and boy am I sick of that sonic screwdriver! I'm going to pack my
> goodies and I'm going home. I said, I'm going to pack my goodies and I
> am going home! Right! Excuse me! (Sarah storms out of the console
> room.)

But after stating that she doesn't *actually* intend to leave, the Doctor says he has to leave her behind while he visits Gallifrey.  But he is, by all appearances, intending to come back for her later:

> SARAH: Don't forget me.
>
> DOCTOR: Oh, Sarah. Don't you forget me.
>
> SARAH: Bye, Doctor. You know, travel does broaden the mind.
>
> DOCTOR: Yes. Till we meet again, Sarah.

He then goes to Gallifrey as promised, and has a rather unusual companion-free adventure (*The Deadly Assassin*, not a great title but a much better episode).  After that is over, he is apparently intending to go back for Sarah (he is, at the very least, aiming to get to London, which is at least approximately where he left her), but the Tardis sends him elsewhere (in the absolutely terribly named but really quite good *The Face of Evil*):

> [Forest]
>
> (Animals call in the night, and a cybermat shaped thing with a small forked tail slithers along the sandy ground as the Tardis materialises amongst dead looking trees. The Doctor steps out, looks around, and speaks to the camera.)
>
> DOCTOR: I think this is not Hyde Park. Could be a nexial discontinuity. Must remember to overhaul those tracers. Put a knot in my hanky.
>
> (His hanky already has a knot in it.)
>
> DOCTOR: I wonder what that was for. Little look round, Doctor? Why not.

He does, of course, end up with an adventure.  And a new companion.  And in the excitement, he clearly forgets about going back for Sarah Jane.  But why did the Tardis send him there?  It's never explained, but it could well be that it does so to *protect* Sarah Jane from spending too much time with him.

(Transcripts from http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/)

Comment: This is contradicted by the narrative of *Face of Evil* establishing that The Doctor had been traveling for some time before making that landing. Indeed, between *The Deadly Assassin* and *Face of Evil*, The Doctor landed on the same planet, did some spoilery things, and had time to forget about it before he returned.

Comment: Do we know that is when he landed there?  Could it not have been on some occasion prior to *The Deadly Assassin*?

Comment: @Politank-Z the Doctor's first visit to that planet actually takes place off-screen during *Robot* from what I recall.

Comment: @Politank-Z The Doctor visited this planet quite some time before Deadly Assassin. He was still in the throes of his post-regeneration confusion period when he came to help, and as such, got things wrong.  The best bet as to when he first arrived was during Robot - the scene where he appears to be leaving, he's actually coming back. The wiki page points out that it's specified in the novelization - http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Face_of_Evil_(TV_story)